# Convert from inline Linq to Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a pretty basic `Linq` statement to fetch all strings in an array that have duplicate letters. The code for this is straight forward, but I can see it being difficult to maintain for some of the less experienced developers on the team (or those less familiar with `Linq`).

```
string[] results = values.Where(v => v.Where(w => v.Count(c => c == w) > 1).Any()).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"There are {results.Length} items with duplicate letters: {string.Join(", ", results)}");
```

I can always break this down into a nested `foreach` loop, or write it several other ways:

```
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    foreach (string v in values) {
        List<char> chars = new List<char>();
        foreach (char c in v.ToUpperInvariant()) {
            if (chars.Contains(c)) {
                results.Add(v);
                break;
            }

            chars.Add(c);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {results.Count} items with duplicate letters: {string.Join(", ", results.ToArray())}");
```

However, I've always wanted to learn more about actual `Linq` queries since they seem quite a bit more readable than inline `Linq`. I prefer to name my variables like I see in the `Linq` queries all the time:

```
List<string> myStrings = from val in values ...
```

I believe that would be more maintainable while still being concise as with most `Linq` code, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the query with it being nested the way it is. I keep trying to write it as:

```
string[] results = from val in values
                   where from currentCharacter in val
                   where ...
```

But I believe it may be more like:

```
string[] results = from val in values
                   join currentCharacter in val on ...
```

I honestly don't think either is the right way to accomplish this, but that is why I am here.

---

How do I convert my nested `Linq` statement from inline to a query?

Comment: It seems like you just ought to create a function that says what you are doing, then hide the messy linq stmt there.

Comment: Honestly, formatting the fluent statement over multiple lines (breaking on periods) and naming the predicate variables more descriptively would go a long way toward it being more readable to anyone, experienced or inexperienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the benefits of using LINQ is that it focuses on *intent* and doesn't bog down the reader in the mechanics.  That's important in maintenance: the sooner you understand what it's doing, the sooner you can figure out how to make the changes required.

Using LINQ syntax (`from ...`) rather than fluent (extension method) syntax may help, too.  As an example, in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52611765#52613950), LINQ syntax made the query much easier to understand.  Either way should be fine, though.

As for converting your nested query, I recommend working outward, so start with your inner query and convert it first.

```
v.Where(w => v.Count(c => c == w) > 1).Any()
```

becomes:

```
(from w in v
 where v.Count(c => c == w) > 1
 select w).Any()
```

Then use that in as the predicate of your outer query:

```
string[] results = (from v in values
                    where (from w in v
                           where v.Count(c => c == w) > 1
                           select w
                          ).Any()
                    select v
                   ).ToArray();
```

Having completed that exercise, it still looks a bit hairy.  Others have suggested making a method of the inner part and I would not disagree with that.  Still, it's good to know how to do the translation, not only so you can make a fully informed decision in this case, but also do it to other queries in the future.

---

Regarding the team's experience, this is a great opportunity to teach LINQ to others at the same time as you're learning it.  Use code reviews or lunch-n-learn sessions to discuss techniques and learn from each other.  *"To teach is to learn twice."*

As a final aside, "LINQ" is the correct casing when speaking of the technology, while .NET naming conventions use mixed case for well-known acronyms, so "Linq" is used in identifiers such as namespaces, e.g. `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the fluent syntax code:

```
values.Where(v => v.Where(w => v.Count(c => c == w) > 1).Any()).ToArray();
```

via query syntax + fluent syntax:

```
var result = (from val in values
              where val.Any(w => val.Count(c => c == w) > 1)
              select val).ToArray();
```

As you can see this still involves method calls and this is simply because some queries *must* be expressed as method calls as there's no query expression syntax for `Any` and `Count` (as far as my knowledge goes anyway).

Basically one way or another, you'll eventually need to involve method calls somewhere in the pipeline.

---

Another thing you might want to do is extract the `where` logic to some method e.g.

```
bool HasDuplicateCharacters(string input) => input.Any(w => input.Count(c => c == w) > 1);
```

then the query would become:

```
 var result = (from val in values
               where HasDuplicateCharacters(val)
               select val).ToArray();
```

Anyone reading this now should know what the code is doing compared to the "fully" fluent syntax above.