# Extracting attribute data from decorated properties

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, attributes

Is there any method to select only the `properties` that are decorated with a specified `Attribute` and extract the `Attribute` data ...all in one pass?

Currently i am first doing a `PropertyInfo` filtering and then i am getting the Attribute data:

Attribute data:

```
public class Weight
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public Weight(string Name,double Value) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}
```

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class WeightAttribute : Attribute
{
    public WeightAttribute(double val,[CallerMemberName]string Name=null)
    {
        this.Weight = new Weight(Name, val);
    }

    public Weight Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Extractor:

```
private static IReadOnlyList<Weight> ExtractWeights(Type type)
{
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<WeightAttribute>() != null);

    var weights = properties
        .Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<WeightAttribute>().Weight)
        .ToArray();

    return weights;
}
```

As you can see in my `Extractor` method i am first filtering the `PropertyInfo[]` and then getting the data's.Is there any other more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, LINQ syntax seems to be avoided when it's actually quite useful and makes the intent ridiculously clear.

Rewritten with LINQ syntax, the following applies @DavidG's excellent point.

```
private static IReadOnlyList<Weight> ExtractWeights(Type type)
{
    return (from p in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            let attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<WeightAttribute>()
            where attr != null
            select attr.Weight).ToArray();
}
```

When queries get even more complex, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52611765/52613950#52613950) (full disclosure: my answer) where the entire method signature needed to be tested, the progressive filtering is easy to follow and facts discovered along the way are highly visible in `let` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and doing the null check as last thing you can avoid getting the custom attributes again:

```
private static IReadOnlyList<Weight> ExtractWeights(Type type)
{
    return type
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        .Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<WeightAttribute>()?.Weight)
        .Where(x => x!= null)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Full example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fbp50c

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get the attributes, do the null check on that and *then* get the weight? Then there is no need for the null-conditional.

Comment: @DavidG then you have to use an additional Select call. But yeah that world work too.